# Is it possible to recreate the functionality of bayesplot's "mcmc_areas" plot in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bayesian, stan

There is a package supported by Stan called `bayesplot` that can produce nice density area plots with the area under the density curves partitioned based on credibility intervals on the posterior parameter samples drawn through MCMC, this results in a plot that looks like the following:

[image: Plot example I want to recreate in ggplot]

I am looking to make a similar style of plot given 1D lists of sampled values using ggplot, that I can pass any generic list of values to without it having to be a Stan fit etc. Does anyone know how to do this? The density part is clear via `geom_density`, but I am struggling with the fill partitioning.

Comment: It's helpful if you can provide example data to work with, along with your question.  That gives all answers a common dataset to work from, which makes it easier to compare solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function that generates a plot similar to `bayesplot::mcmc_areas`. It plots credible intervals (equal-tailed by default, or highest density) with optional setting of the probability width of the interval:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
library(bayestestR)
theme_set(theme_classic(base_size=15))

# Create ridgeplots with credible intervals
# ARGUMENTS
# data A data frame
# FUN A function that calculates credible intervals
# ci The width of the credible interval
# ... For passing optional arguments to geom_ridgeline. 
#      For example, change the scale parameter to control overlap of ridge lines. 
#      geom_ridgeline's default is scale=1.
plot_density_ridge = function(data, FUN=c("eti", "hdi"), ci=0.89, ...) {
  
  # Determine whether to use eti or hdi function
  FUN = match.arg(FUN)
  FUN = match.fun(FUN)
  
  # Get kernel density estimate as a data frame
  dens = map_df(data, ~ {
    d = density(.x, na.rm=TRUE)
    tibble(x=d$x, y=d$y)
  }, .id="name")
  
  # Set relative width of median line
  e = diff(range(dens$x)) * 0.006
  
  # Get credible interval width and median
  cred.int = data %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols=everything()) %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(CI=list(FUN(value, ci=ci)),
              m=median(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
    unnest_wider(CI)
  
  dens %>% 
    left_join(cred.int) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(y=name, x=x, height=y)) +
      geom_vline(xintercept=0, colour="grey70") +
      geom_ridgeline(data= . %>% group_by(name) %>%
                       filter(between(x, CI_low, CI_high)),
                     fill=hcl(230,25,85), ...) +
      geom_ridgeline(data=. %>% group_by(name) %>% 
                       filter(between(x, m - e, m + e)),
                     fill=hcl(240,30,60), ...) +
      geom_ridgeline(fill=NA, ...) + 
      geom_ridgeline(fill=NA, aes(height=0), ...) +
      labs(y=NULL, x=NULL)
  
}
```

Now let's try out the function

```
# Fake data
set.seed(2)
d = data.frame(a = rnorm(1000, 0.6, 1),
               b = rnorm(1000, 1.3, 0.5),
               c = rnorm(1000, -1.2, 0.7))

plot_density_ridge(d)
plot_density_ridge(d, ci=0.5, scale=1.5)
plot_density_ridge(iris %>% select(-Species)) 
plot_density_ridge(iris %>% select(-Species), FUN="hdi")
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent, thank you, one small thing to note is that mcmc_areas uses equal tailed intervals rather than highest density, was momentarily confused as to why the outputs were slightly different, might be worth amending the solution to use eti (available in the bayestestR package) or at least note that this is the case.

Comment: One question I have remaining is how to make it so that the ridges don't overlap, seems fine for you but when I create plots using your function the ridges tend to overlap each other and appear much larger?

Comment: See updated answer. The function now provides a choice of ETI or HDI and uses ETI by default. I've also shown how to use the `scale` argument to control ridgeline overlap.

Comment: I get the following error with your example : ```Joining, by = "name"
Erreur : Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is `between(x, CI_low, CI_high)`.
x `left` must be length 1
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: name = "a". ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ggridges`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

tibble(data_1, data_2, data_3) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = name, group = name)) +
  geom_density_ridges()
```

[image]

Data:

```r
set.seed(123)
n <- 15
data_1 <- rnorm(n)
data_2 <- data_1 - 1
data_3 <- data_1 + 2
```